# What are the performance implications of sharding?

Tags: database, performance, join, sharding

I am new to sharding and wanted to know what implications sharding has for various queries. For the sample data set named "people":

```
person_id | person_fname | person_lname | person_dob
----------------------------------------------------
1         | John         | Smith        | 1972-03-04
2         | Sally        | Jones        | 1968-09-14
3         | Phil         | Forrester    | 1976-11-25
4         | Gwen         | Langley      | 1955-04-20
5         | Pedro        | Romero       | 1962-12-21
6         | Gene         | Halford      | 1978-01-11
7         | Juan         | Peza         | 1977-08-07
8         | Pierre       | Henry        | 1980-04-30
```

The data is sharded equally across four nodes by creating a hash of the surrogate identity "id". However, you need to perform read and write operations on records that potentially span all the nodes such as:

```
SELECT person_fname, 
       person_lname 
FROM   people 
WHERE  person_dob > '1970-01-01'
```

Or say you had a further table of "orders", which references "people" on the "person_id" column, and wanted to perform a join...

```
SELECT    order_id,
          order_amount,
          order_date,
          person_fname,
          person_lname
FROM      orders
LEFT JOIN people
WHERE     order_amount > 50
```

Is it the case that in effect all of the nodes will run the query in parallel? I am assuming that each server will have less work to do for each step as instead of one instance running the query over eight records, simultaneously, four instances will run the query over two(ish) records, with the further benefit that if the DBMS is able to perform shard selection then the other nodes need not continue executing any further instructions, is this assumption correct?

Are there any known performance implications with sharding and complex joins (beyond that of this simple example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will indeed allow that to be done in parallel.

It can indeed make joins complex, and hence slower, if they have to cross different shards.

However, with a many-to-one, if you had e.g. `orders` sharded in such a way that all rows in the `orders` table where in the same shard  as the related row in the `people` table, then this cross-shard problem doesn't happen.

You need to design your sharding approach so you get lots of cases like that and few (ideally none) where you end up crossing shards.

You also want to have your shard on the key you actually seek on the most. Eg. if you are finding people by username as your starting point to everything else, then you want to shard by username, not id, because when then finding them you already know which single shard to hit, rather than having to hit all of them just to get back zero rows from most.

Comment: Sadly, the above falls into the "easier said than done" category.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sharding introduces severe changes in performance. It *never* allows the application to be left unchanged.

The most sane way to shard is if the data model allows for data to be partitioned to be truly independently. Like in a multi-tenant situation where the tenants don't interact at all. In this case joins never span partitions and all is good.

This get very very nasty when sharding with cross-partition interaction. Writing a query that runs against all shards has a cost linear in the number of partitions. This means that you get zero speedup by adding nodes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite follow, "It never allows the application to be left unchanged", what do you mean by this?

Comment: When you decide to shard an application performance characteristics usually change so the app oftentimes has to be modified in many places.

Comment: Ah right, so if you decide to go sharded from unsharded you are more than likely going to have to change the way your application works to avoid the pitfalls? Is there no performance benefit gained from being able to parallelize the query across multiple nodes, or is it typical that the added complexity of the workload negates this?

Comment: Small OLTP query don't really benefit because calculation time is often less than per-query overhead. OLAP does benefit from this big time if you transfer little data between the nodes (like aggregate 10TB sales over 50 countries - perfectly scalable, just aggregate per-node and merge the results).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for [ScaleBase](http://www.scalebase.com/), a maker of a complete scale-out solution an "automatic sharding machine" if you like, looks and feels like 1 MySQL, proxy to a grid of "shards", automating command routing and parallelizing cross-db queries, and merge results - you wouldn't see a difference from a result that would have come from 1 DB. ORDER, GROUP, LIMIT, agg functions supported! The routing and parallelizing is done inside the "controller" according to the command and parameters.

From experience with our customers, not only had we got great performance improvements with parallel queries, we also improved maintenance, think about creating an index, adding a column to a table - these are also parallelized and run much faster. All with none or pretty minimal changes to the code.

Your query examples are classic examples of "all-db" executions that will definitely run faster if distributed and parallelized. Indexes are more efficient, RAM is used, etc...

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks Doron, how does it compare with MySQL Cluster auto-sharding setup?